# How to restrict space at first position in ckeditor textarea using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

This my ckeditor div code

```
<div>
    <div class="QB-PanelName"><lable>Question</lable></div>
    <textarea name="QBQuestion" id="QBQuestion" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>                 
 </div>
```

and this is javascript/jquery code
this is the cdn used for CKeditor http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.0/basic/ckeditor.js

```
CKEDITOR.replace('QBQuestion');

     CKEDITOR.instances.QBQuestion.on('key', function (evt) {
            var kc = evt.data.keyCode;
            console.log(evt);
            if (kc === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
               }
        });
```

it is not working to restrict space in the first position.
I have updated jquery code but in that kc===32 is completely not allowing space but my requriement is in first position only i don't want space

[image]

Comment: It's working in snippet editor here...

Comment: actually this ckeditor code it is not working on keypress i have kept alert but alert also not coming i think it is not going inside

Comment: I have added image of inspecting element in the question

Comment: can anyone give solution for this?

Comment: I have updated jquery code but in that kc===32 is completely not allowing space but my requriement is in first position only i don't want space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#QBQuestion'))
  .then(editor => {
    editor.editing.view.document.on('keydown', function(evt, data) {
      if (data.keyCode === 32 && $(data.domTarget).text().length === 0) {
        data.stopPropagation();
        data.preventDefault();
        evt.stop();
      }
    }, { priority: 'highest' });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

**Demo**

```js
ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#QBQuestion'))
  .then(editor => {
    editor.editing.view.document.on('keydown', function(evt, data) {
      if (data.keyCode === 32 && $(data.domTarget).text().length === 0) {
        data.stopPropagation();
        data.preventDefault();
        evt.stop();
      }
    }, { priority: 'highest' });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/15.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="QB-PanelName">
    <lable>Question</lable>
  </div>
  <textarea name="QBQuestion" id="QBQuestion" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution but i am using cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.0/basic/ckeditor.js this plugin

Comment: @Arun I suggest that next time you ask a question then you include all relevant information.

Comment: sure but sorry for this time